# highlight html inside a cross platform mobile app ios androd windows

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I working on cross platform app. It has a few html docs inside and it has to be shown inside app as webview.  There is a requirement to do a search for a keyword and if the match found in html , the html will be loaded in web view as the matched occurrences of keyword in red color. 
Can any one help?
Thanks
Joseph

Comment: Note that the app is for ios, android and windows

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question so that someone could understand what you're doing. Currently this question is too broad.

Comment: I did not add any code for highlighting, I have the data to be displayed. In native app I was using a webview and I created the dynamic html data with those words with a different color. Essentially appending data in parts. But now I am rewriting it for crossplatform and there could be easy way instead on old method. I can also use the full htm file with all data present in that.But I need specific words higlighted with color, What could be easy way to  do that?